# error vite react No cargan los datos del backend en mobile celular [Posible solucion en proceso]

Tags: mysql, reactjs, programación-móvil, vite

hay un error con vite react, no renderiza los datos del backend al fronted en mobile,  pero usando /ping  o rutas con res json el backend si responde.

```
github:https://github.com/dev-ronaaldll/try-mern-mysql-crud
```

Tengo una solucion pero quiero saber si alguien me puede ayudar.

Comment: El código debe ir _en la pregunta_, no como un enlace externo (problamente por eso tampoco hayas recibido ayuda aún). Recuerda que preguntar y responder en el sitio representa también ayudar a los demás quienes tengan un problema similar. Lee [ask] y pon un [repro] del problema en cuestión. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio: ten siempre presente que [es.so] _no es un foro_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 Solucion reemplazar fetch/axios de " localhost " a " ip/192.168.1.100 "
>
> 2 Solucion usar una configuracion de  proxy en `vite y react`